# How to change HTML element value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have DIV and inside div it has table. I want to change the one of the column value of table using java script. I can do it by getting the element id of column, **but there is no any id assigned** to any table's column. Below is the example.

```
<div id="usersec">
<TABLE style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 279px; HEIGHT: 70px">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD style="FONT-FAMILY: Verdana" vAlign=center align=middle>Talk to me </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
</div>
```

Is it possible to change the "Talk to me" text using javascript?

Comment: Do you only ever have the one `<td>` in the table?  Or are you asking us how to find a _specific_ `<td>` without an `id` attribute, eg based on its _content_?

Comment: Are you happy to use a lib, such as jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to get the element and then set a new value to `element.innerHTML`. It's easiest if you give an `id` to the element that you want to change but you don't need to

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SxSXC/2/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var usersec = document.getElementById('usersec');
    var td = usersec.getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
    td.innerHTML = 'New value';
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If your userbase is IE8+, you can safely use `querySelector`:

```
var container = document.getElementById('usersec');
var td = container.querySelector('tr:first-child > td');
if(td){
  td.innerHTML = "New Text!";
}
```

Here's a JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/YkhwE/

`querySelector` (or `querySelectorAll`) allow you to target elements in the DOM via CSS syntax, which is very useful. It's very well supported, in every current and previous browser. (via [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector))

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an id to the TD, and use that;

```
<div id="usersec">
<TABLE style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 279px; HEIGHT: 70px">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD style="FONT-FAMILY: Verdana" vAlign=center align=middle id="cellToChange">Talk to me</TD>
</TR></TBODY></TABLE>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("cellToChange").innerText = "Go on, talk to me please!";
</script>
```